# How do I find and calculate specific data of an Excel file within R?

Tags: r, excel, rgui

I have a large Excel file with data that looks like the following throughout:

[image: Sample of Excel file.]

I know I can use something like

`data[which(data$Label == "Crop Sales ($)"),c(1,5,6,7)]`

to be able to dictate which value in the "Label" column I want to be shown. However, what I want to be able to do is calculate the total amount of "Crop Sales($)" from each state to be able to see which state had the highest or lowest amount of crop sales.

For example, I want the table to look like the following :

[image: Example of table]

except I would like the "Value" column to be combined so that there is only one row for each state with a combined total of crop sales.

Is there any way that this can be done?

Also, some of the values in the "Value" column contain values of "-" or "(D)" and are therefore not integer values, will this make a difference?

Comment: `aggregate(Value~state+Label,data,sum)`?

Comment: @Onyambu when I run that code I get the following error: "Error in Summary.factor(c(18912L, 10203L, 34345L, 32287L, 11662L, 20207L,  : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors".. any ideas?

Comment: That is because your values were read in as factors...

Comment: first, do `aggregate(Value~state+Label,transform(data,Values=as.numeric(as.character(Values))),sum)` there will be warning due to the fact that there is `(D)` within that row...

Comment: oh okay I see what you mean, I think I got it now, thanks!